# GCSE maths question concerning indices

Tags: linear-algebra

Today was my GCSE maths exam, and I found it perfectly straightforward - except for one question. The question was:

Given that $(2^\frac1 2)^n = \frac{2^x} {8^y}$

Find $n$ in terms of $x$ and $y$

Clearly a simple answer would be $n = log_\sqrt2 (\frac{2^x} {8^y})$. However, logarithms are not on the GCSE syllabus, so there must be a way to solve it algebraically. Can somebody please provide me a step-by-step solution to the problem? Thank you for your help.

Also, I apologize for the small equation size (I'm new to mathjax). Please edit to incrase size if that is possible.

Comment: $8=2^3$ and go from there to get n = 2(x-3y). Fill in the bits!

Comment: @Paul I quite literally just slumped to the floor. I cannot believe that i missed that >.<

Comment: No reason not to mark your answer as correct though i reckon.

Comment: @Paul I hope so. Unfortunately many of the examiners aren't maths teachers so may only mark an answer correct if it's on the mark scheme. You never know, maybe that solution is one there.

Comment: Very true - best of luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the denominator on the right is $(2^3)^y = 2^{3y}.$

Then $$2^\frac{n}{2} = \dfrac{2^x}{2^{3y}} \iff 2^\frac{n}{2} = 2^{x-3y} \iff \frac n2 = x-3y \iff n = 2x - 6y$$

Recall that $$\frac{a^b}{a^c} = a^b\cdot a^{-c} = a^{b-c}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I realize now that didn't realize I needed to convert $8^y$ to $(2^3)^y$. My stupidity surprises me sometimes xD

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

[As](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Exponent_Combination_Laws/Power_of_Power) $(a^m)^n=a^{mn}$

and $\displaystyle 8^y=(2^3)^y=2^{3y}\implies \frac1{8^y}=2^{-3y}$

Finally $\displaystyle a^m=a^n\iff a^{m-n}=1 $ for $a\ne0$

either $m-n=0$

or $a=1$

or $a=-1,m-n$ is even